# Unable to delete AppEngine Service instance using App Engine Admin API

Tags: google-app-engine

I am attempting to programmatically delete an App Engine (Standard) backend instance. The code for deleting it runs as a Servlet on another module/service of the same project.

I am able to list the instance and all the details, but attempting to delete it throws the 403 error.

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I am using the App engine default service account:

```
AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential(Arrays.asList(AppengineScopes.APPENGINE_ADMIN));

Appengine engine = new Appengine.Builder(new UrlFetchTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName("AppEngineManager").build();
//list all instances - this works fine

//now delete an instance
engine.apps().services().versions().instances().delete(appId, serviceId, version, <instanceid>).execute()
```

The default App engine service account has Editor role (I also tried manually adding App Engine Admin role, to no avail)

The service account name printed before running the code is also correct. What could be wrong?

Comment: I have tried deleting via the REST api explorer and it works (but it uses my personal account which is an Admin on the project) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/delete

Comment: An investigation yesterday revealed the Editor role was unexpectedly missing the `appengine.services.list` permission (when using `gcloud` to switch traffic between service versions), possibly related to your problem. The issue dissapeared today. Give it another try, just in case.

Comment: Thank Dan, but I have been trying this the whole day today (and even now after your comment), but same problem. MOreover, I have even explicitly tried adding the "App Engine Admin" & "App Engine Service Admin" which have these roles, but still didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved it!

```
AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential(Arrays.asList(AppengineScopes.**CLOUD_PLATFORM**));
```

I was using the more obvious looking AppengineScopes.APPENGINE_ADMIN, but this doesn't work. Wish Google would improve their documentation. Had sleepless nights because of a production issue which required us to delete the instances programmatically to solve it.

Comment: About the docs, in the [Admin API's REST method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/delete) that you linked in the comment under the question the authorization scope is described as: "Requires the following OAuth scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" - and this is the change that helped you, switching the scope to CLOUD_PLATFORM.